# Jenkins Last Changes plugin and changes in subdirectory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have an SVN repository and a Jenkins job which is configured to poll changes only in a certain subdirectory (I use "included regions" feature for this.) 
I want to use the Last Changes Plugin to publish changes. But if I do this, the plugin publishes ALL changes on the whole repository. Is it possible to make the plugin to publish ONLY those changes that triggered the build? (That is, those in "included regions".)

Comment: If anyone is interested in a solution: I decided to split out the subdirectory into an own git repository and created then a pipeline job onto it. If you need a plugin-only solution, you could maybe extend the plugin yourself (or create a feature request) to consider only your sub-directory's comits.